# Hot-plug in detect by Interrupt

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, udev

I am currently using udev to detect USB hot-plug event in my application but as far as I know its a polling process, it requires one thread continuously monitoring kernel uevent.
Is there any way that kernel notifies me by an interrupt or it signal to my process whenever Hot-Plug event detected?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/hotplug.txt)?

Comment: How are you currently polling?

Comment: using udevadm monitor and i also did it by creating netlink socket to listen uevent, but stil its a polling technique, in my application there are lots of threads already and one more thread for polling is costly for me

Comment: you could create a `udev` rule to send a signal to your process when a matching device is plugged in

Answer (score 0):

First write a udev rule to identify the device and run a script (action) when that device is connected to the host.

1. Get the information of your device with below command, in my example, it is USB console adapter. This command will report a bunch of things that we can use to identify the device on hotplugging by means of udev rule file.

> $ udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0

Now make a file - /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbdev.rules with below content.

> SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="xxxx",
>   ATTRS{product}=="USB to UART Bridge Controller",
>   RUN+="/usr/bin/devattached.sh"

**Reload udev rules and service:**

```
$ udevadm control --reload-rules
$ systemctl restart udev.service
```

**Debug:** if the udev rule is not working!!

```
udevadm monitor --udev
```

2. Make a script with your desired action and put it on the exact same path provided in 'RUN+'. Don't forget to give executable permission to that script. Make use of pgrep and kill commands to send the signal to your process from the script.

Comment: how to identify the process id in shell script, if multiple processes are running of same name @SD

Comment: You should `getpid()` your process within the code and store it somewhere and use when needed.

Comment: i have to signal my process whnever hotplug in is detected, i am using PID=`pgrep myApp` in my script but what if multiple process of same name is running , in that case it always sends signal  to the process having lowest process id

Comment: You can do something like this - printf("myApp process ID: %d\n", getpid()); write code to store this pid somewhere on the filesystem - e.g in /var/run/myApp.pid file. Read pid from /var/run/myApp.pid file in script and send the signal.

Comment: `killall -s SIGNAL myApp` would send the `SIGNAL` to all `myApp` processes